# Cygwin wants to downgrade my Perl

Tags: cygwin, perl, downgrade

I'm using Cygwin 2.769.  I used `setup.exe` to upgrade Perl to version 5.14.1-2, which works fine.  But now whenever I open `setup.exe` to upgrade/install some other package, it by default wants to downgrade Perl back to 5.10.1-5.  If I don't remember to manually cycle that box over to my current version each time, Perl gets downgraded without my noticing.

Is this expected behavior, or have I hosed something up?  It seems like using the "Curr" setting should not by default downgrade things.

[I [previously asked this on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491445/cygwin-wants-to-downgrade-my-perl), I'm manually migrating it here.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

5.10.1-5 is the "current" version and 5.14.1-2 is the "experimental" one, which is why if you have the overall selection set to "Curr", you get 5.10.1-5.

There are a few ways around this, although none of them are terribly satisfactory.

- Select "Exp", to get you the experimental versions of all packages that have one. Usually there aren't many.
- Select "Keep", but of course this way you miss out on updates.
- Stick with "Curr", and manually set perl back to the desired version every time you run setup.exe.

"Curr"'s behaviour is needed to allow one to easily get back to "stable" versions of all packages after installing experimental ones, but a different setting that updates packages to their current versions but that doesn't downgrade anything would indeed be nice to have.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, the main problem would be deciding what to call it. ;-)